# .NET Library to handle DateTime output nicer

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, nuget-package

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I calculate relative time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11/how-do-i-calculate-relative-time)

I did stumble upon a nice library some time ago that gives you a nicer way when we're dealing with Dates like:

`@DateTime.AddDays(-1)` will show `yesterday`

`@DateTime.Now` will show `Just now`

WHat is the technical term of this and, did you guys know the [nuget package](http://nuget.org) of this library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a jQuery plugin out there called timeago, which can also do what you're looking for: http://timeago.yarp.com/